# How to save current aspx page as html

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Please tell me how to save current page as a html page on button click. My page contains only labels which I fill on page load event.

I am using the code below for this, but it's not saving (in HTML) all of the values that I see when my page is loaded (I think it converts before the values get loaded on the page).

```
private void saveCurrentAspxToHTML()
{
    string HTMLfile = "http://localhost:4997/MEA5/AEPRINT.aspx?id=" +
                      Convert.ToString(frmae.AeEventid) +
                      "&eid=" +
                      Convert.ToString(frmae.AeEnquiryid);

    WebRequest myRequest = WebRequest.Create(HTMLfile);

    // Return the response.
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

    // Obtain a 'Stream' object associated with the response object.
    Stream ReceiveStream = myResponse.GetResponseStream();
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");

    // Pipe the stream to a higher level stream reader with the required encoding format. 
    StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(ReceiveStream, encode);

    // Read 256 charcters at a time.
    Char[] read = new Char[256];
    int count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~") + "\\MyPage.htm"))
    {
        while (count > 0)
        {
            // Dump the 256 characters on a string and display the string onto the console.
            String str = new String(read, 0, count);
            sw.Write(str);
            count = readStream.Read(read, 0, 256);
        }
    }

    // Close the response to free resources.
    myResponse.Close();

}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 5):

I'm a little sketchy on the actual code. But a while ago I did something similar. I used a StringWriter to write the content of the aspx to html string.

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
  HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
  divForm.RenderControl(w);
  string s = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
```

Then basically you just have to write that to a string file and save it as an HTML extension.

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\yoursite.htm", s);
```

Comment: can you please give some demo or documentation?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's already 6 years since the question was posted. But, I got a good reference here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2004/Jun/08/Capturing-Output-from-ASPNet-Pages

Perhaps it will be useful for the other reader.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
        // *** Write the HTML into this string builder
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

        HtmlTextWriter hWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        base.Render(hWriter);

        // *** store to a string
        string PageResult = sb.ToString(); //PageResult contains the HTML

        // *** Write it back to the server
        writer.Write(PageResult)
}
```